# How to save html report generated by spark-df-profiling on azure blob?

Tags: python, pyspark, profiling, azure-blob-storage

I am using spark-df-profiling package to generate profiling report in azure databricks. But `to_file` function within ProfileReport generates an html file which I am not able to write on azure blob.

Already tried:

1. wasb path with container and storage account name
2. created empty html file, uploaded on blob and using that url to write
3. generated sas token for above created empty file and given that url

```
profile = spark_df_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_file(paths in already tried)
```

I want to save the output on this path provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I reviewed the source code of version `v1.1.13` of `julioasotodv/spark-df-profiling`, I solved it via the code below. First, please refer to Azure Databricks offical document [`Data Sources > Azure Blob Storage`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) and [`Databricks File System`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/databricks-file-system.html#dbutils) for `dbutils` to know how to write data to a specified data source like Azure Storage.

Here is my sample code, it works for me on Azure Databricks and Azure Storage.

```
storage_account_name='<your storage account name>'
storage_account_access_key='<your storage account key>'
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
  storage_account_access_key)

# My sample pandas dataframe for testing
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

import spark_df_profiling
from spark_df_profiling.templates import template
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
profile = spark_df_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
dbutils.fs.put("wasbs://<your container name>@ppas.blob.core.windows.net/test.html", template('wrapper').render(content=profile.html))
```

I can see it works via the result `True` and output 29806 bytes to Azure Blob, then to check it in Azure Storage Explorer.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It is working fine.'from spark_df_profiling.templates import template' mad the things quite easy